# How to open Bootstrap Photo Gallery on page load?

Tags: media, theming

I am using [Bootstrap Photo Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_gallery), and would like to open the slideshow when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Add your gallery into model window then used #modelid in then then gallery is automatically load when your page is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It would be  jQuery('#bootstrap-gallery').show(); but it doesn't work. Doesn't create an error either but blocks off access to the gallery. Additional complication - borderless gallery option' which says it doesn't use modal. Closest I got was with >  window.bootstrap.Gallery(jQuery('.view-photographer-of-the-year  a'), jQuery('#blueimp-gallery').data()); FInding an unminified version of the drupal code is hard.